# Why doesn't ansible have an archive module?

Tags: ansible

Googling for *Ansible create tar* doesn't yield any good results and while there is an *unarchive* module, there's no *archive* module.

I'll probably solve it with the *command* module, but being new in Ansible it makes me think if I'm doing it wrong. I'm pretty sure I'm not the first one in need of taring source code to be uploaded to the production server.

So why is there no archive module and how does the community handle this use case?

Comment: Wouldn't storing your sources in a revision control system such as git/subversion and deploying specific releases make much more sense than deploying tar or zip archives?

Comment: Yes, this is something I plan to improve, though I'm expecting some pushback. That's for another discussion. Right now I have to tar a part of the source locally. Maybe this is the reason, because everybody just checks out the source on production.

Comment: _Why?_ Ansible's mailing list is probably a better place to ask.

Comment: Zips aren't used only for RCS. :-) Amazon's Lambda takes code in the form of a zip file.

Comment: I've been looking for this for marathon deployments so I can access private docker containers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Module has been added in Ansible 2.2 as an extra module, see:

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/archive_module.html

Answer (score 3):

It seems the Ansible folks welcome the idea, but demand has actually not been large enough for someone to step up and create such a module:

- [related SO question with source code for `shell` approach](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33405379)
- [*Module Request: Extract and Archive* on GitHub](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/2097)
- [*trying to write a tar module/action_plugin* Ansible mailing list post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ansible-project/jIrTAVm6Wd4)